# Why laravel 5 migration hasTable not work in some cases with PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, migration

I am experiencing problems using Migrations and postgresql in Laravel 5. This is when I'm performing table existence checks before performing any action on migrations files.

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //@todo this is not work!
    if (Schema::hasTable($this->personSchema . 'person')) {
        Schema::table($this->personSchema . 'person', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('person_person_user_id_foreign');
        });
    }

    Schema::drop($this->accountsSchema . 'users');

    PGSchema::drop($this->accountsSchemaName);
}
```

Some of the checks just do not work and that action is not performed.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Which of the checks aren't working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, no errors. This is not work: if (Schema::hasTable($this->personSchema . 'person')) ..

Answer (score 2):

Try to bring your configuration settings to this form:

```
    /* ... */
    'driver'    => getenv('DB_CONNECTION'),
    'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'database'  => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'schema'    => 'testing',
    'strict'    => true,
    /* ... */
```

I guess the problem is that you use the "$this->schema", and Laravel is trying to find a table named "schema.scape", and not "schema"."scape", because of this, and an error occurs.
Try schemes specify only in the configuration file or in the extreme case, try to use the DB::raw($this->schema.'.scape')

For example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableTestscape extends Migration
{
private $schema = "testing";

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    \Pacuna\Schemas\Facades\PGSchema::create($this->schema);

    if (!Schema::hasTable('scape')) {

        echo 'Creating table than not exists' . "\n";

        Schema::create('scape', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestampsTz();
        });
    }

    if (Schema::hasTable('scape')) {

        Schema::table('scape', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        });


        echo 'Altering table and adding reference of foreign key' . "\n";

        Schema::table('scape', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('accounts.users');
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    echo 'Deleting at all data' . "\n";

    Schema::dropIfExists('scape');

    \Pacuna\Schemas\Facades\PGSchema::drop($this->schema);
}
}
```

Laravel will take the scheme from the configuration and add it to the desired table.
The source code Laravel has the following code for PostgreSQL:

```
public function hasTable($table)
{
    $sql = $this->grammar->compileTableExists();

    $schema = $this->connection->getConfig('schema');

    if (is_array($schema)) {
        $schema = head($schema);
    }

    $table = $this->connection->getTablePrefix().$table;

    return count($this->connection->select($sql, [$schema, $table])) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will post more details in here.

Answer (score 0):

My Friend @Самуил-Клад, I will how I try it with migration file.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableTestscape extends Migration
{
    private $schema = "testing";

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        \Pacuna\Schemas\Facades\PGSchema::create($this->schema);

        if (!Schema::hasTable($this->schema . '.scape')) {

            echo 'Creating table than not exists' . "\n";

            Schema::create($this->schema . '.scape', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->timestampsTz();
            });
        }

        if (Schema::hasTable($this->schema . '.scape')) {

            echo 'Creating user_id foreign key' . "\n";

            Schema::table($this->schema . '.scape', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            });


            echo 'Altering table and adding reference of foreign key' . "\n";

            Schema::table($this->schema . '.scape', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('accounts.users');
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        echo 'Deleting at all data' . "\n";

        Schema::dropIfExists($this->schema . '.scape');

        \Pacuna\Schemas\Facades\PGSchema::drop($this->schema);
    }
}
```

But the `user_id` column is not created.

What's happening?

In below has a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I create a Issue at Laravel framework github repo: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/846#issuecomment-288421520